# Why do ZeroMemory, etc. exist when there are memset, etc. already?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, memset

Why does `ZeroMemory()`, and similar calls exist in the Windows API when there are memset and related calls in the C standard library already? Which ones should I call? I can guess the answer is "depends". On what?

Comment: One important reason would be integrating (unifying) the interface. We should also think about the history - not all programming plans go as planned. MS has a long history in this world so there are many historical reasons here and there in general. Generally, in the programming world, it is helpful to think about the _intention at the time_ of planning(or designing) even if it has not actually become a reality.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In C and C++, `ZeroMemory()` and `memset()` are the exact same thing.

```
/* In winnt.h */
#define RtlZeroMemory(Destination,Length) memset((Destination),0,(Length))

/* In winbase.h */
#define ZeroMemory RtlZeroMemory
```

Why use `ZeroMemory()` then? [To make it obvious.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050628-07/?p=35183) But I prefer `memset()` in C or C++ programs.

Comment: It's a bigger issue, as I noted in my answer: optimizing compilers can remove calls to `memset()`, so you really want to use something which won't be optimized away.

Comment: @richard.albury in that case you should use SecureZeroMemory, as ZeroMemory could be optimized away.

Comment: @ya23 I hate to "Well, actually", but that's exactly what I said in my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

The actual reason is that on a different platform it might be implemented in a more efficient way than `memset`. Don't forget that Windows NT was designed as a highly portable operating system, it actually ran on Alpha, MIPS and Power PC. So, if the fooPC platform came out and has some assembly way to ultra-fast set memory to zero, it can be implemented without changing the high level API. This is no longer true for Windows, since now it only supports x86 and amd64 platforms, however it is still true for Windows CE.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason.  If an efficient way to zero memory exists, they could incorporate that into the `memset` implementation, too.

Comment: @Maxpm in Windows there isn't a system provided C standard library. Each executable links (often statically) with the C library provided by its compiler.

Answer (score 10):

`ZeroMemory` and such are part of the windows API itself. `memset` is part of the C standard library.

For typical userland code, I'd normally use `memset` (or the equivalent provided by your language of choice). If you're writing kernel code (e.g., a device driver) using something like `ZeroMemory` is more attractive. Since your code executes in kernel mode anyway, you don't incur the cost of a task switch to use it. Since it's already in the Windows code, you aren't carrying around extra code in your driver to duplicate what's already there. At the same time, you do incur the cost of a function call, and in the case or zeroing (especially a small block of) memory, inline code may be significantly faster, and a `rep stosd` doesn't take much code (in fact, setting up and using `rep stosd` may take less code that a function call).

Comment: In newer Visual Studio compilers `memset()` is an intrinsic function. That means that it is implemented by compiler itself and in many cases there's no function call. Compiler inlines it with specially crafted assembly code to perform best based on target architecture, length and memory alignment of data being overwritten.

Comment: @BJovke: that's not a particularly recent innovation. It goes back to at least MS C 6.0 (note: MS C, not VC++), which (going for memory, so it could be a little wrong) was released around 1989 or '90. I guess I didn't say it directly in the answer, but that was the point of mentioning the overhead of a function call (i.e., that using `ZeroMemory` would involve a function call, but using `memset` often wouldn't).

Answer (score 8):

Because the Windows API should be language-agnostic. It provides sufficient functionality for developers, regardless of the language they use. Of course, eventually many functions will duplicate existing functionality offered by the languages.

You should call the winapi functions (and *macros*) directly whenever you need a certain level of control -- compare `fopen()` with `CreateFile()` for instance. Otherwise, prefer language-specific constructs over API calls. At least, you gain more platform-independence.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would write a language-agnostic macro.

Comment: ZeroMemory appears to be a macro for cross MS-language nomenclature. I checked as it was possibly a system trick for hardware memory clearing which could have been more efficient. It is probably just syntactic sugar for memset; ignore it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366920(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Pete: if you have ZeroMemory defined in the C stdlib and - say VBA - then your coder uses the same name for the same purpose and is better locked-in to Microsoft. Embrace and extend, brother! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish

Comment: @Pete ouch! Macro or not, isn't it a part of the Windows API?

Comment: @Humberto It is part of the Windows API, but the Windows API is defined in C. Why do you believe the Windows API should be language agnostic?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, what you **want** to use is [`SecureZeroMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

An optimizing compiler can remove calls to `memset()`, and `SecureZeroMemory()` is designed to prevent this.

I used to think the `ZeroMemory()` calls were unnecessary until I came across this fact.

Answer (score 5):

Because, ZeroMemory don't require line of comment

Answer (score 3):

I think one point is that the memory allocation functions should look the same in all Win32 projects, independent of the programming language. Indeed, as have been pointed out before, in C, ZeroMemory is actually memset, the C function. In Delphi,

```
procedure ZeroMemory(Destination: Pointer; Length: DWORD);
begin
  FillChar(Destination^, Length, 0);
end;
```

where FillChar is the Delphi function. And so on:

```
procedure MoveMemory(Destination: Pointer; Source: Pointer; Length: DWORD);
begin
  Move(Source^, Destination^, Length);
end;

procedure FillMemory(Destination: Pointer; Length: DWORD; Fill: Byte);
begin
  FillChar(Destination^, Length, Fill);
end;

...
```

Comment: Really out of topic, but as a Delphi developer, I tend to use MoveMemory (or CopyMemory - they're identical) when I have pointers, and Move when I have variables, so I do not have to use "@" or "^".

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366920(VS.85).aspx), ZeroMemory is a macro. It probably exists as a convenience (e.g., naming convention) or for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'd go with the backwards compatibility, along with those functions for handling 32 bit numbers (I forget the names) for division etc.