# Difference Between Memset and ZeroMemory

Tags: memory, winsock

I'm coding up a simple (old) fashioned way to write a socket program and there is a part where there is

```
memset(&addrinfo, NULL, sizeof(addrinfo));
```

in Unix/Linux or Windows. In the MSDN tutorial, Microsoft uses

```
ZeroMemory(&addrinfo, sizeof (addrinfo));
```

I was just wondering, is there any difference between the two functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do ZeroMemory, etc. exist when there are memset, etc. already?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038302/why-do-zeromemory-etc-exist-when-there-are-memset-etc-already)

Answer (score 1):

According to @dante:

In Win32, `ZeroMemory` is just a macro around `RtlZeroMemory`, which is a macro to `memset`. So, I don't think it makes a difference.

WinBase.h:

```cpp
#define ZeroMemory RtlZeroMemory
```

WinNT.h:

```cpp
#define RtlZeroMemory(Destination,Length) memset((Destination),0,(Length))
```