# C++ Windows ZeroMemory vs { 0 }

Tags: c++

Is there any difference between using `ZeroMemory(&buffer, SIZE_OF_BUFFER)` and `buffer = { 0 }` in C++ on windows?

Comment: Depends on the type of `buffer` and the value of `SIZE_OF_BUFFER`. It's certainly possible to construct a program where the two have different meaning.

Comment: Let's say you have a `char buffer[256];`

Comment: Then the second won't compile.

Comment: If you do it from the get-go it will

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "get-to" here. I'm going by the code you've shown, not by some different code you may have in your mind.

Comment: The real point is which one is a Windows specific code and which one is C++ standard code?

Comment: From the get-go means if you do it like this `char buffer[256] = { 0 };`; it will compile. My question is if doing `char buffer[256] = { 0 };` or using `ZeroMemory(&buffer, 256);` after initializing makes any difference.

Comment: Then why don't you edit your question and say so? Anyway - the end result is the same, but the compiler may be able to produce a better-optimized code for the former. `ZeroMemory` is a macro that ultimately expands to `memset` call, which the compiler may or may not be able to inline.

Comment: It was pretty implicit that's what I meant when writing telling you about the char buffer since that's the only way it will compile. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038302/why-do-zeromemory-etc-exist-when-there-are-memset-etc-already